# How to resize image as I scroll?

Tags: java, android

I have a ScrollView in which I have inserted a ConstraintLayout that contains a fullscreen ImageView and some other components below it.

What I want is for the image to shrink in height (to a certain limit) whenever I scroll down.

Here's an example of what I'm seeking: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QksCo.jpg

As for resizing, after some research I figured I'd have to create a LayoutParams object and then affect it to the ImageView. No problem there.

But as for detecting the scroll event, I've had some trouble. I tried the setOnScrollChangeListener on my ScrollView, but the problem is that it requires an API level of at least 23. So I wonder if there is another solution that works for lower levels as well.

Another problem I'm having is how to make the resizing proportionate to how much the user has scrolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to do the coordinator layout with a collapsing toolbar. This is built into android and you do not need any code changes. The inflater will inflate the layout and everything will work.

In your xml layout file you will need

```
 <coordinatorlayout

<Appbar layout
<collapsingtoolbar
<ImageView>  <-- your image goes here
/collapsingtoolbar
/Appbar layout
/coordinatorlayout

<nestedscrollview

<textview> <--Your content that moves up goes here

/nestedscrollview
<floating action button> <-- your example shows one of these buttons but its optional
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for!